# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first - Foreach loop if statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, runtime-error

I am trying to loop through a list of hazards to see if a control measure has been added in ControlMeasures for each hazard.
If each hazard has a control measure then I set complete to true, if not I break the foreach loop leaving complete set to false.

I have written the foreach loop below but at runtime I get the following error showing against the if condition statement:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

I have done some reasearch and it would appear that I have not written the code in the correct manner but as I'm still new to this I can't work out a better and correct way of writing it.

```
[HttpGet]
    public ViewResult AddControlMeasure(int raId)
    {
        // Get list of hazardids for this RA  
        IEnumerable<int> hazardIds = db.RiskAssessmentHazards.Where(x => x.RiskAssessmentId == raId).Select(x => x.HazardId);

        var complete = false;
        foreach (int HazardsId in hazardIds)
        {
            if (db.ControlMeasures.Where(x => x.HazardId == HazardsId && x.RiskAssessmentId == raId).Count() == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                complete = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you need to add a `.ToList` or `.ToArray` at the end of your `hazardIds` selection, otherwise it won't close the connection on that reader until you've gone through the entire enumeration. I'm also sure there is a way to do without the for-loop but I'm drawing a blank at the moment.

Comment: Possibly because the `db.RiskAssessmentHazards` returns `IQueryable`, so hasn't actually executed by the time you do the foreach loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
IEnumerable<int> hazardIds = db.RiskAssessmentHazards
    .Where(x => x.RiskAssessmentId == raId).Select(x => x.HazardId);
```

Returns a lazy-evaluated sequence (really an `IQueryable` that will not hit the database until you begin enumerating (the `foreach`).

The loop:

```
foreach (int HazardsId in hazardIds)
{
    ...
}
```

Will open the connection to the database, get the reader, and, for each iteration, move along the reader to get the data.  This means that the connection has an active reader for the duration of your loop.

Finally, this line:

```
if (db.ControlMeasures.Where(x => x.HazardId == HazardsId && x.RiskAssessmentId == raId).Count() == 0)
```

Tries to use the connection (associated with your `db`) to perform *another* query.  Since you already have an active reader due to the `foreach` loop's queryable, this introduces the error you've received.

Notwithstanding that it's generally a bad idea to execute a query within a loop, the simplest solution would be for you to use `.ToArray()` or some other way to fully realize the results before iterating the loop:

```
int[] hazardIds = db.RiskAssessmentHazards
    .Where(x => x.RiskAssessmentId == raId)
    .Select(x => x.HazardId)
    .ToArray();
```

That way the reader will be closed before you begin iterating your loop and executing the subsequent queries.

Comment: Thanks very much for a great answer, Ive learnt alot and fixed the problem

Answer (score 2):

Methods like `Where, Select,GroupBy` and `OrderBy` use deferred execution (which cause open DataReader like in your case). These methods don't force the query to execute, so the query execution is deferred until enumerated. Therefore you should do enumeration yourself with `ToList()` or `ToArray()`.

In your case you should force enumeration for `hazardIds' like

```
IEnumerable<int> hazardIds = db.RiskAssessmentHazards
                            .Where(x => x.RiskAssessmentId == raId)
                            .Select(x => x.HazardId).ToArray();
```

Comment: @BasharAbuShamaa No problems. Glad that it helped.)